# android:drawableStart shows image on Graphical Layout but not in emulator or physical device

Tags: android, android-button, android-drawable

I believe the title sums it up pretty well. I have a Button within a RelativeLayout. My goal is to have both text and a small leaf image on the left side of said text, for that I have used `android:drawableStart`. Here´s what baffles me: the Graphical Layout does show the image, but when emulator is run the buttons display without the image. I have also tried it on different versions with physical devices, same story.

I have no idea what could be wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:background="@drawable/background" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/neverMind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_neverMind"
        android:textColor="#E4F5ED"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_shadow" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/button_leaf"
        android:onClick="finish"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I apply the following xml to style the button: (titled button_shape_shadow.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <corners
               android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
               android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
           <solid android:color="#3D6652" />
           <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
                         android:top="10dp" />
     </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="6dp" android:top="6dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                     android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
                     android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
                     android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                     android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#3D6652" />
            </shape>
         </item>
         <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
           <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#87D1AC"    
                        android:startColor="#62A382" />
                <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#62A382" />
                <corners
                     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                     android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                     android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
                         android:top="10dp" />
           </shape>
         </item>
    </layer-list>
 </item>
```

Here is an image of what I see. The first button shows what I want and what the **Graphical Layout** does show. The second button is what appears on a physical device or when an emulator executes it.

[image]